# How to show type hierarcy in Xcode 8?

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to draw things on a map (which is a `MKMapView`). `MKMapView` has an `add(overlay : MKOverlay)` method which allows you to add an overlay.

The tutorial I am following uses a `MKGeodesicPolyline` as the argument to the `add(overlay : MKOverlay)` method. `MKGeodesicPolyline` is a subclass of `MKPolyline`, where `MKPolyline` conforms to `MKOverlay`.

However, I would like to know what else (apart from `MKGeodesicPolyline`) I can pass to `add(overlay : MKOverlay)` method of a `MKMapView`. To know this, I need to learn everything that conforms to `MKOverlay`, either directly, or as being a descendant of a class which conforms to `MKOverlay` directly.

How can I do this? I have used the symbol navigator but couldn't do what I wanted to achieve.

How can I get a list of classes which I can pass to `add(overlay : MKOverlay)` method?

Answer (score 1):

I'd just search for it.  According to Xcode's built-in documentation for `MKOverlay`, the following classes adopt the protocol:

• `MKCircle`

• `MKPolygon`

• `MKPolyline`

• `MKTileOverlay`